# How to add survey in a landing page?

Tags: landing-page, marketing-cloud, microsites, survey

Is there any way to add a survey on a landing page (in salesforce marking cloud / exact target)?

Currently, the only way to send survey to contacts is by embedding a survey in an email which does not work in outlook.

I am trying to add a survey with questions on a landing page but I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

The Survey Tool you describe in indeed limited and has short comings when it comes to putting surveys in email, as a Form directly inside the email is dependent on the handling capabilities of the email client.

Best practice & recommendation would be to link to a survey on a Webpage / Cloud Page.

If you are using Cloud Pages, you could build a custom survey and use the 'Voting' gear. You'll have greater compatibility and control of your design and process.

You could also use the 'Survey Monkey' gear in Cloud Pages; or if you are feeling really confident you could build a raw HTML site in Cloud Pages and use AMPScript to store the data in data extensions.

[image]